# Client application hangs while waiting for response from WCF

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wcf

We have a WPF application, which makes requests to WCF services which are hosted as windows service.
The call to the service is on a different thread. However, it is noticed that, when there is some sort of time wait or sleep on the WCF side, the WPF application hangs.
The Instance context mode on the service is set to single. Is this a concern?

How can we make the client more responsive? Why should a sleep on the service make the client wait even when the call is not on the UI thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to make sync call to WCF service.

You should try calling the service in Async mode.

Following link may help you.

[Async Call to WCF - 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730059.aspx)

[Async Call to WCF - 2](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/How-to-Implement-a-WCF-2090bec8)

Comment: Why should a synchronous request in a separate thread block the UI?

Comment: On synchronous call, till the response, GUI thread will be blocked. If you call it asynchronously, GUI will stay responsive.